# Staticmethod as property without instantiation

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have a `class` which is used to hold a bunch of python static methods which will return a string from an environment variable.

```py
class GitLabCiEnv():
    """
    Gitlab CI Environment variables.
    """
    @staticmethod
    def CHAT_CHANNEL() -> str:
        """
        Source chat channel which triggered the ChatOps command.

        Added in GitLab 10.6
        Available in GitLab Runner all
        """
        return os.environ["CHAT_CHANNEL"]

    @staticmethod
    def CHAT_INPUT() -> str:
        """
        Additional arguments passed in the ChatOps command.

        Added in GitLab 10.6
        Available in GitLab Runner all
        """
        return os.environ["CHAT_INPUT"]
```

With this `class` I can just call `GitLabCiEnv.CHAT_CHANNEL()` to get the value of the environment variable. The "ugly" is, that I have to use paranthesis for each those `@staticmethod`.
What I would do is `GitLabCiEnv.CHAT_CHANNEL` without paranthesis.

I do not want to instantiate an object of this class, there is, in my opinion no benefit of having an object.
I tried different implementations, using class variables, but then each variable will be initialized if the class is imported, this is not what i want.

Maybe someone has a solution for me.

Thank you very much!

Comment: use classmethod ?

Comment: "in my opinion no benefit of having an object" Correct. In fact, there is also no benefit of having a class as there does not seem to be any state that needs to be tracked. These methods should probably just be a module-level functions

Comment: "I have a class which is used to hold a bunch of python static methods" that is something that shouldn't be a class then. Probably just a module with functions

Comment: Yes I thought about the "module with functions" but then, I wouldn't get rid of the parentheses. Because the return values are more ore less "static/constant" I want, that the enduser (who uses this class) has an interface as simple as possible.
Maybe if someone would give me an example how to implement it in other ways I will check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably shouldn't be a class. But if you really want this, just create a custom descriptor:

```
import os

class EnvProxy:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        return os.environ[self.key]

class GitLabCiEnv:
    CHAT_CHANNEL = EnvProxy("CHAT_CHANNEL")
    CHAT_INPUT = EnvProxy("CHAT_INPUT")
```

An example:

```
(py38) juanarrivillaga@50-254-139-253-static Project-Roche-2 % CHAT_INPUT=foo python -i test.py
>>> GitLabCiEnv.CHAT_INPUT
'foo'
```

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. I tested it and can confirm, that is exactly what i want. 
But can you give me a little bit of explanation what is going on? Thank you.

Comment: @dvonessen read this: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html